# Get enum values at index path SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, enums

I have this model that I use on a tableview and populate it with:

```
struct TestSection {
   var title: String
   var options: [TestOption]
}

struct TestOption {
   var field: String
   var placeholder: String
}
```

```
var models = [TestSection]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

models.append(TestSection(title: "Test", options: [
            TestOption(placeholder: "Test"),
            TestOption(placeholder: "Test 2"),
            TestOption(placeholder: "Test 3")
        ]))
}
```

After using a delegate to pass back some data I can change the models values at a specific index like so:
models[0].options[1].placeholder = value

I want to achieve the same thing but with an enum. My model with an enum looks like this:

```
struct TestSection {
   var title: String
   var options: [TestOptionType]
}

enum TestOptionType {
   case testOneCell(model: TestOptionOne)
   case testTwoCell(model: TestOptionTwo)
   case testThreeCell(model: TestOptionThree)
}

struct TestOptionOne {
   var field: String
   var placeholder: String
}

struct TestOptionTwo {
   var tag: Int
   var placeholder: String
   var handler: (() -> Void)
}

struct TestOptionThree {
   var firstName: String
   var lastName: String
   var handler: (() -> Void)
}
```

```
models.append(TestSection(title: "Description", options: [
            .testOneCell(model: TestOptionOne(field: "Test", placeholder: "Test")),
            .testTwoCell(model: TestOptionTwo(tag: 1, placeholder: "Test", handler: {
             ///handle handler
             })),
            .testThreeCell(model: TestOptionThree(firstName: "Test", lastName: "Test", handler: {
             ///handle handler
             }))
        ]))
```

How can change the values of one of my structs using models[0].options[0]. When I try it I can only add 'self' to the end of options like this 'models[0].options[0].self' but that is not what Im looking for.

Comment: What if you wrote some code to change `options[0].field` because you _thought_ `options[0]` is the `testOneCell` case, but when that line is executed, `options[0]` is actually `testTwoCell`, and it doesn't have a `field` property?

Comment: what you need is `models[0].options[0] = .testOneCell(model: .init(field: "", placeholder: ""))`

Answer (score 1):

Since `TestOption` is an enum, the value of `models[0].options[0]` could be one of three cases, and in each case, a different struct value is associated with it.

You seem to want to set the property of one of the specific option types (`TestOptionOne`, `TestOptionTwo` or `TestOptionThree`). Well, you can't do that without making sure that there *is* actually a value of that type associated with the enum value. For example, to set `models[0].options[0].field`, you have to make sure that `models[0].options[0]` is of the case `testOneCell` first. To do that:

```
if case .testOneCell(var optionOne) = models[0].options[0] {

    // after we do the check, we can set the entire enum, but only changing field to a new value
    models[0].options[0] = .testOneCell(TestOptionOne(
        field: "This is a new value for field", placeholder: optionOne.placeholder
    ))
} else {
    // You should decide what to do when the enum is not of case testOneCell
}
```

Doing this every time is quite annoying, so you can extract this into a mutating function and put it in the enum:

```
mutating func setOptionOne(mutator: (inout TestOptionOne) -> Void) {
    if case .testOneCell(var optionOne) = self {
        mutator(&optionOne)
        self = .testOneCell(model: optionOne)
    } else {
        // You should decide what to do when this is called and the enum wasn't of case testOneCell
    }
}

mutating func setOptionTwo(mutator: (inout TestOptionTwo) -> Void) {
    if case .testTwoCell(var optionTwo) = self {
        mutator(&optionTwo)
        self = .testTwoCell(model: optionTwo)
    } else {
        // You should decide what to do when this is called and the enum wasn't of case testTwoCell
    }
}

mutating func setOptionThree(mutator: (inout TestOptionThree) -> Void) {
    if case .testThreeCell(var optionThree) = self {
        mutator(&optionThree)
        self = .testThreeCell(model: optionThree)
    } else {
        // You should decide what to do when this is called and the enum wasn't of case testThreeCell
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
models[0].options[0].setOptionOne { $0.field = "This is a new value for field" }
```